# Convert CSV document to XML

Tags: python, xml, csv

I know the question is redundant but I tried all the Python code that I found and modified for my file but they did not work. I need to find a way to convert my file [myData.csv](http://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/tournagesdefilmsparis2011) in to a XML format file which can be read by a navigator.

I just started to learn Python this month so I'm a beginner. This is my code:

```
#! usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv, sys, os
from lxml import etree


csvFile = 'myData.csv' # création de la variable pour le fichier csv
reader= csv.reader(open(csvFile), delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) # création d'une variable reader à qui on renvoie le tableau csv

print "<data>"
for record in reader:
    if reader.line_num == 1:
        header = record
    else:
        innerXml = ""
        dontShow = False
        type = ""
        for i, field in enumerate(record):
            innerXml += "<%s>" % header[i].lower() + field + "</%s>" % header[i].lower()
            if i == 1 and field == "0":
                type = "Next"
            elif type == "" and i == 3 and field == "0":
                type = "Next"
            elif type == "" and i == 3 and field != "0":
                type = "film"

            if i == 1 and field == "X":
                dontShow = True

        if dontShow == False:
            xml = "<%s>" % type
            xml += innerXml
            xml += "</%s>" % type
            print xml
print "</data>"
```

Comment: Sorry , for somes unknown reasons the code and the link doses not appear well, can someone help me fix it , thank you!

Comment: yes! i need to download it and then use it to convert to xml!

Comment: You should add some explanation to your question, telling us the problem you are having with that code. (Also, since you are a beginner you should probably be learning Python 3).

Comment: But we use either use python 2 or 3. the teacher did not specify which one we should use! some uses 3  others 2.  (Sorry for my english , i am NOT A NATIVE SPEAKER OF ENGLISH

Answer (score 2):

Consider building your XML with dedicated DOM objects and not a concatenation of strings which you can do with the `lxml` module. Using methods such as `Element()`, `SubElement()`, etc. you can iteratively build XML tree from reading CSV data:

```
import csv
import lxml.etree as ET

headers = ['Titre', 'Realisateur', 'Date_Debut_Evenement', 'Date_Fin_Evenement', 'Cadre',
           'Lieu', 'Adresse', 'Arrondissement', 'Adresse_complète', 'Geo_Coordinates']

# INITIALIZING XML FILE
root = ET.Element('root')

# READING CSV FILE AND BUILD TREE
with open('myData.csv') as f:
    next(f)                             # SKIP HEADER
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in csvreader:        
        data = ET.SubElement(root, "data")
        for col in range(len(headers)):
            node = ET.SubElement(data, headers[col]).text = str(row[col])

# SAVE XML TO FILE
tree_out = (ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8"))

# OUTPUTTING XML CONTENT TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tree_out)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <data>
    <Titre>1</Titre>
    <Realisateur>BUS PALLADIUM</Realisateur>
    <Date_Debut_Evenement>CHRISTOPHER THOMPSON</Date_Debut_Evenement>
    <Date_Fin_Evenement>21 mai 2009</Date_Fin_Evenement>
    <Cadre>21 mai 2009</Cadre>
    <Lieu>EXTERIEUR</Lieu>
    <Adresse>PLACE</Adresse>
    <Arrondissement>PIGALLE</Arrondissement>
    <Adresse_complète>75018</Adresse_complète>
    <Geo_Coordinates>PLACE PIGALLE 75018 Paris France</Geo_Coordinates>
  </data>
  <data>
    <Titre>2</Titre>
    <Realisateur>LES INVITES DE MON PERE</Realisateur>
    <Date_Debut_Evenement>ANNE LE NY</Date_Debut_Evenement>
    <Date_Fin_Evenement>20 mai 2009</Date_Fin_Evenement>
    <Cadre>20 mai 2009</Cadre>
    <Lieu>DOMAINE PUBLIC</Lieu>
    <Adresse>SQUARE</Adresse>
    <Arrondissement>DU CLIGNANCOURT</Arrondissement>
    <Adresse_complète>75018</Adresse_complète>
    <Geo_Coordinates>SQUARE DU CLIGNANCOURT 75018 Paris France</Geo_Coordinates>
  </data>
  <data>
    <Titre>3</Titre>
    <Realisateur>DEMAIN, A L'AUBE</Realisateur>
    <Date_Debut_Evenement>GAEL CABOUAT</Date_Debut_Evenement>
    <Date_Fin_Evenement>17 avril 2009</Date_Fin_Evenement>
    <Cadre>17 avril 2009</Cadre>
    <Lieu>EXTERIEUR</Lieu>
    <Adresse>RUE</Adresse>
    <Arrondissement>QUINCAMPOIX</Arrondissement>
    <Adresse_complète>75004</Adresse_complète>
    <Geo_Coordinates>RUE QUINCAMPOIX 75004 Paris France</Geo_Coordinates>
  </data>
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you! but when i tried  your code , the terminal is retruning me  : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    node = ET.SubElement(data, headers[col]).text = str(row[col])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Check if the `headers = [...]` line matches columns in actual CSV. This solution uses the one in link above. Possibly, you are working with a different version. And please be aware XML tags cannot have space or special characters as CSV might. See how I used underscore for *'Adresse_complète'*.

Answer (score 0):

(posted as an answer so I can show a code block)

There are a lot of picky details when writing XML.  In Python, you should probably use some version of ElementTree to help with that.  One good tutorial is [Creating XML Documents](https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html).  Quoting from there:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

top = Element('top')

comment = Comment('Generated for PyMOTW')
top.append(comment)

child = SubElement(top, 'child')
child.text = 'This child contains text.'

child_with_tail = SubElement(top, 'child_with_tail')
child_with_tail.text = 'This child has regular text.'
child_with_tail.tail = 'And "tail" text.'

child_with_entity_ref = SubElement(top, 'child_with_entity_ref')
child_with_entity_ref.text = 'This & that'

print(tostring(top))
```

If you use this as an example of how to create a tree of XML elements, you should be able to translate your code into the XML structure you need.

Answer (score 0):

Importing pandas and saving file name:

```
import pandas as pd
csvFile = 'myData.csv'
```

The following will read CSV into a pandas data frame, then convert to XML.

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df_xml = df.to_xml()
```

The below code will create a new file and then save the XML data to a file named "csv2xml"

```
f = open("csv2xml.xml", "w")
f.write(df_xml)
f.close()
```